# How would i encode certain $_GET params?

Tags: php, encoding

Im currently using base64_encode for some $_GET params that i don't want regular user to mess with.
I was wondering that base64 is not looking too strong or is it ?

I also don't want to make some sort of mega encoding it's not so much of important information, but i would not like that user with average knowledge would mess with params in get.

Should i keep using base64 ? Currently it produces `MQ==` if value is 1 so it's quite easy to take it out from URL and decode and then insert your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some real encryption/decryption take a look at the Mcrypt features of PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php

But then you may want to use POST instead of GET because of the URL specifications which are limited in character usage and URL length.

Comment: could still put the result through base64_convert and gzcompress

Answer (score 4):

[Base-64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) doesn’t protect the data in any way. It’s a simply base conversion like using hexadecimal instead of decimal for integers.

If you just want to verify [data integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity), you can use a salted hash (with a secret salt) that you store along with the data. See for example the [hashed message authentication code (HMAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Comment: seems like he doesn't need real encryption: "not so much of important information, but i would not like that user **with average knowledge** would mess with params in get"

Answer (score 3):

[`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) [is not a security measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)! It was designed to make sending of binary blobs possible through mediums that typically transfer ASCII only.

Use a session, or properly encrypt your variables.

I would recommend just using a session, and storing it out of the default `/tmp` for good measure with...

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/sessions');
```

Comment: I don't want to hide values for security measure i just want to convert it to something that regular web user will not understand and could not edit just like that.

Comment: @arma I'm a regular web user that could edit your values. I can see the string has a pattern like `1AzJjKosS97Zj` and make a good guess it is base 64 encoded. Then I could decode it easily, change it, and reencode and send as a GET param.

Comment: @arma: if you don't want users to edit the string, then you need a security measure

Comment: Hmm i don't think session will work in my case. I need to send values to 3rd party website as GET then receive same values by POST. So ideally the idea here would be to encode GET part then when POST received decript that one.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want do do with it.

If you just want to obfuscate it (especially when you're generating those URLs in Javascript or so), you could apply ROT13 to the URL and swap a few additional characters to make decoding it a little bit more difficult.

However, if the security of your application depends on it, you could apply a static-key symmetric encrytion on the data server-side and decode it when you receive a request or so. I think that there are frameworks or so for that.